# DatabaseError when using facebook login on django-social-auth

Tags: django, facebook, django-socialauth

I have a django app, and would like to use django-social-auth for facebook/twitter authentication.

I've installed the django-social-auth app and deployed my app on heroku. The home page shows up fine, and when I click, "login using facebook", I am redirected to the correct facebook login page. However, after I click login, I am taken to a page with this error:

```
DatabaseError at /complete/facebook/
relation "social_auth_usersocialauth" does not exist
```

What exactly is the issue here? And how can I go about solving it?

Comment: Have you done `syncdb` and `migrate`?

Answer (score 1):

I had just forgotten to do syncdb and migrate.